# Android: Remove a SharedPreference before updating value?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Should you remove the old SharedPreference before updating the value of it...Like such:

```
Editor.remove("KEY1");//remove old value
Editor.putString("KEY1", newValue);//same key, new value
Editor.apply();
```

or does

```
Editor.putString("KEY1", newValue);//just add new value
Editor.apply();
```

just overwrite the old data without consequence?

Comment: I see the "down vote" fairy has visited......An explanation of why this is a bad question would be nice, aside from the usual "Shows lack of research, blah, blah," I felt this was a legitimate question with what my be a simple answer but I just wanted to know from the millions of users with huge knowledge what the correct action was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the old value will be overwritten.